# sql server 2005 syntax for insertion

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, ado.net

My query is this and I want to insert but em using SQL Server 2005

```
insert into postad(cityid,category_id,ad_id,title,ad_description,subcategory_id) 
values((select city_id from city where city_name='mumbai'),
(select cat_id from category where cat_name='automobiles & vehicles'),
(select adid from adType where adtype like'wanted'),'myad','itys grwweefa',
(select subcat_id from  subcategory where category_id =
    (select cat_id from category where cat_name like'automobiles & vehicles')))
```

Can any one help me how can I achieve this

```
    string city = ddcity.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string cat = ddcat.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string subcat = ddsubcat.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    string adtype = ddadtype.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string title = txttitle.Text.Trim();
    string description = txtdescription.Text.Trim();
    string video = txtvideo.Text.Trim();
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DELL-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=eclass;Persist Security Info=True;integrated security = true");
    string cityq = "select city_id from city where city_name=" + city;
    string catq = "select cat_id from category where cat_name=" + cat;
    string subq = "select subcat_id from city where subcat_name=" + subcat+"and category_id="+catq;

    SqlCommand storead = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO postad " + "(cityid,category_id,ad_id,title,ad_description,subcategory_id,video,date_creation) " + " values (@city,@cat,@adtype,@title,@description,@subcat,@video,@date)", myConnection);

storead.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title",title);
storead.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city",city);
storead.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat",cat);
storead.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subcat",subcat);
storead.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adtype",adtype);
storead.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description",description);
storead.Parameters.AddWithValue("@video",video);
storead.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",date)
```

This is how it has to work n id's are primary key

Comment: what's wrong with your current query?

Comment: its saying syntax is wrong!!!

Comment: always tag your DB related questions with DBMS that you are using

Comment: Oh, and please don't bother to accept any of the answers that have been given to any of your questions before. That would be highly inappropriate.

Comment: @shweta: @Uw Concept was being somewhat sarcastic. You should go back and accept answers to questions if they helped you resolve the problems you had.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO postad(
  cityid, category_id, 
  ad_id, title, ad_description, 
  subcategory_id)
VALUES 
  SELECT TOP(1) city_id, cat_id, ad_id, 'myad', 'itys grwweefa', subcat_id
  FROM city, category, adType, subcategory
  WHERE city.city_name='mumbai'
    AND category.cat_name='automobiles & vehicles'
    AND adType.adtype like 'wanted'
    AND subcategory.category_id = category.cat_id
```

This is untested code

---

**Edit:** Move your `INSERT` Statement into a Stored procedure and replace all the string values in my query with the parameters

```
INSERT INTO postad(
  cityid, category_id, 
  ad_id, title, ad_description, 
  subcategory_id)
VALUES 
  SELECT TOP(1) city_id, cat_id, ad_id, @title, @description, subcat_id
  FROM city, category, adType, subcategory
  WHERE city.city_name=@city
    AND category.cat_name=@subcat
    AND adType.adtype like @adtype
    AND subcategory.category_id = category.cat_id
```

Comment: TOP(1) is used to make sure you only select the first matching row http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This i doubt would work as there may be multiple rows returned in the subquery's - all the subqueries should return the same number of rows to insert into the table.

The question is not really clear about what needs to be acheived, please revise.

Comment: will it work after adding top 1 to each of inner select queries?

Comment: That might resolve the immediate errors and allow the query to run, but whether it would have the intended result is another matter altogether.